# Crieria Builder setMaxResults sort issue

Tags: java, criteria

I have written a query in Criteria Builder, its looks like this.

```
private EntityManager entitymanager;
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entitymanager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object> criteriaQuery = 
criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object.class);
Root<Employee> from = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(name));
TypedQuery<Object> typedQuery1 = entitymanager.createQuery(criteriaQuery );
List<Object> resultlist1 = typedQuery1.getResultList();
typedQuery1.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
```

After setMaxResults apply to the query, the order of the resultlist1 is 
different as before? 
Why is this happened?
How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: Have you print out both sql (the sql generated by the JPA that one have setMaxResults and one does not) for debugging?

Comment: yes, I have, I see this by debugging. The List is different after setMaxResults.

Comment: It might be because of the DB you are using. If you are using Oracle DB, ROWNUM < your_count SQL will be generated. Which DB are you using.?

We could try:
1. criteria.addOrder(Order.asc(""));
2. Inner query like "select * from(select * from user where param<= 500 order by x) where ROWNUM < your_count;"

Comment: I use H2 Database

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using Object for type? Use Employee

```
CriteriaQuery<Employee> criteriaQuery = 
criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> from = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(from.get("column_name")));
TypedQuery<Employee> typedQuery1 = entitymanager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
typedQuery1.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
List<Employee> resultlist1 = typedQuery1.getResultList();
```

Calling setMaxResults() after executing query does not make sense. Set max result before calling getResultList()

```
typedQuery1.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
List<Employee> resultlist1 = typedQuery1.getResultList();
```

What is `name` variable? Do order by like this:

```
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(from.get("column_name")));
```

Comment: because I map some usefull data from employee to Object

Comment: Don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: Set max result before calling getResultList()

Comment: okey, I set max result before calling getResultList(), but it doesnt solve my issue. Because each time when I calling the query with the same condition, I become a List with different order.

Comment: What is name variable? Do order by like this:

`criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(from.get("column_name")));`

Comment: I solve the problem by changing the ordering. Now, I have a suborder like this: criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(name), criteriaBuilder.asc(city));

Comment: @SengülMor Glad to hear that. It is a good habit to mark answer as correct then